# Textarea character counter not working on dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created table and on the click of a button a modal opens. The first time I click on any button and enter values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JROxC.jpg

And then for the next time if I click on another button, it shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz7je.jpg

91 characters remaining, but it should show 100 characters remaining as it is another modal.

My HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" class="email" > Notify Via Email<br></p>
  <p><label for="message">Message </label>
     <textarea rows="3" name="message" id="message"  class="form-control input-md message" onclick="remainingChar()"></textarea></p>
   <div id="textarea_feedback" class="textarea_feedback"></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
function remainingChar(){
var text_max = 100
$('.textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');
$('.message').keyup(function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var length = text_max-length;
    $('.textarea_feedback').html(length + ' characters remaining');
});
}
```

Comment: You need to reset count on button click

Comment: Your `modal-body`div is missing a closing `>` -- is that a typo here or in your original HTML?

Comment: Its by mistake...but > is present in my original HTML

Comment: Add button click event code that opens the modal

Comment: "as it is another modal." .. if you are creating duplicate modals, it creates duplicate ID's which means trouble. Second: you would have to use context (the correct modal) to ensure you target the correct elements. Last, you are only updating that number which clicking on the textarea, not when showing the modal (see skobaljic's answer).

Comment: Thank You So much...I considered all points raised by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your `remainingChar()` function on your modal raise, something like:

```
$('.raise-modal-button').on('click', function{
    remainingChar();
    $('.modal-body').show();
});
```